# If $a$ and $b$ are constants, calculate the definite integral

Tags: integration

$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} F(x-b) f(x-a) dx$$

$$f(x) = \exp(-x-e^{-x}), \qquad x \in (-\infty, +\infty)$$

$$F(x) = \int_{-\infty}^x f(t) dt$$

I calculated already the integral of $F(x)$, which is $\exp(-e^{-x})$, but I am stuck on the other one, I have no idea how to calculate the integral of $F(x-a)f(x-b)$.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Answer (score 1):

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}F(a-b)f(x-a)dx=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-e^{-(x-b)}} e^{-(x-a)} e^{-e^{-(x-a)}}  dx=$$

$\Rightarrow e^{a} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-e^{-x}({e^{b}+e^{a}})} e^{-x}   dx$

Now Let,  $-e^{-x}=t,  \rightarrow e^{-x} dx =dt$

$\Rightarrow e^{a} \int_{-\infty}^{0} e^{t{(e^{a}+e^{b}})}   dt~~$

$\Rightarrow \frac{e^a}{e^{a}+e^{b}}.$